# geom_line(): styling legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to make a plot using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(fit.pre.net, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, col = "Predicted (before SOEs)", linetype = "Predicted (before SOEs)"), size = 1) +
  geom_line(fit.mid.net, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, col = "Predicted (during SOEs)", linetype = "Predicted (during SOEs)"), size = 1) +
  geom_line(fit.post.net, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, col = "Predicted (after SOEs)", linetype = "Predicted (after SOEs)"), size = 1) +
  geom_line(fit.pre.count, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, col = "Counterfactual (before SOEs)", linetype = "Counterfactual (before SOEs)"), size = 1) +
  geom_line(fit.mid.count, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, col = "Counterfactual (during SOEs)", linetype = "Counterfactual (during SOEs)"), size = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Predicted (before SOEs)" = "solid", "Predicted (during SOEs)" = "solid", "Predicted (after SOEs)" = "solid",
                                   "Counterfactual (before SOEs)" = "dashed", "Counterfactual (during SOEs)" = "dashed")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Predicted (before SOEs)" = "steelblue4", "Counterfactual (before SOEs)" = "steelblue4",
                                "Predicted (during SOEs)" = "red", "Counterfactual (during SOEs)" = "red", "Predicted (after SOEs)" = "seagreen4"))
```

And the legend looks like this:
[image]

1. Why does it show linetype and color separately, and how to combine them?
2. I saw another example where "dashed" actually looks like "dashed", instead of just being a bit shorter than "solid" legend. Why and how to fix this?
3. Right now, legend appeared on the right side of the graph. Is there a way to make it smaller and place it at the lower left bottom?

I want to assign color and linetype as follows:

"Predicted (before SOEs)": steelblue4, solid

"Predicted (during SOEs)": red, solid

"Predicted (after SOEs)": seagreen4, solid

"Counterfactual (before SOEs)": steelblue4, dashed

"Counterfactual (during SOEs)": red, dashed

Could anybody please tell me how to fix this issue?

---

As suggested in the comment, I tried this instead:

```
p <- ggplot
  geom_line(fit, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, col = group, linetype = group), size = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Predicted (before SOEs)" = "solid", "Predicted (during SOEs)" = "solid", "Predicted (after SOEs)" = "solid",
                                   "Counterfactual (before SOEs)" = "dashed", "Counterfactual (during SOEs)" = "dashed")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Predicted (before SOEs)" = "steelblue4", "Counterfactual (before SOEs)" = "steelblue4",
                                "Predicted (during SOEs)" = "red", "Counterfactual (during SOEs)" = "red", "Predicted (after SOEs)" = "seagreen4"))
```

The data looks like this now:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   x           y group                       
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                       
 1 2018-01  24.7 Predicted (before SOEs)     
 2 2020-03  25.1 Predicted (before SOEs)     
 3 2020-04  25.3 Predicted (during SOEs)     
 4 2021-09  25.0 Predicted (during SOEs)     
 5 2021-10  25.2 Predicted (after SOEs)      
 6 2022-07  25.2 Predicted (after SOEs)      
 7 2020-04  25.1 Counterfactual (before SOEs)
 8 2021-09  25.4 Counterfactual (before SOEs)
 9 2021-10  25.0 Counterfactual (during SOEs)
10 2022-07  24.9 Counterfactual (during SOEs)
```

I then found that I can change legend place and size by adding the following code inside `theme()`:

```
legend.text=element_text(size=10),
legend.justification=c(0.05,0.05),legend.position=c(0.05,0.05),legend.title=element_blank()
```

Now, 1 and 3 are solved, but my dashed legend still looks weird... What could be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Convert the data wide-to-long then plot.

Comment: Now you need more space for lines in the legend, so the dashes show up: `theme(legend.key.size = unit(3, "lines"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your linetypes are not properly visible in the legend key is that the size of the lines in the legend key are too large to see the `linetype` aesthetic.  The solution for this problem is to explicitly define the `size` to use in the legend to be smaller.  By default, the legend key aesthetics match what is drawn by the `geom_*()` command, but you can redefine the aesthetics to use in the legend or change the size of the keys to fix the problem.

#### Example of the Problem

Here's an example that demonstrates this problem well and the fix above.  First, here's the basic plot:

library(ggplot2)

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color=Species, linetype=Species))
p + geom_line()
```

[image]

In the plot above, you can easily differentiate `linetypes` in the legend.  Note that the size and aesthetics of the legend keys match what is displayed in the main panel.  Let's see what happens when we define a larger size for the lines within `geom_line()`:

```
p + geom_line(size=1.8)
```

[image]

Look familiar?  The larger line size relative to the legend key size causes the legend keys to not look correct.  You can fix this by *either* making the legend keys larger or by redefining the aesthetics to use for drawing the legend.

#### Fix 1: Changing Legend Size

To change the size of the legend, you can use `theme()` elements `legend.key.size` or `legend.key.width`, or `legend.key.height`.  I like `legend.key.width` here, since we're looking at horizontal lines:

```
p + geom_line(size=1.8) +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(40, 'pt'))
```

[image]

#### Fix 2: Changing Legend Aesthetics

A potentially better solution (in my mind) is to define explicitly the aesthetics to use in the legend.  This can be used to tell `ggplot` to "draw it smaller" in the legend:

```
p + geom_line(size=1.8) +
  guides(
    linetype=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1))
  )
```

[image]

The fix to use will depend depend on your particular plot and how it looks compared to the legend as well as personal preference.